# MariaDB connection times out on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I am migrating my backend written in C to NodeJS, and the MariaDB connector for C always works, but the NodeJS connector times out for me. Does anyone seem to know why this is happening? I even put some markers that print 0, 1, 2, 3 for each newer scope and I only get 0 printed out:

```js
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mariadb');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var https = require('https');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');

var pool = mysql.createPool({host: 'localhost', user: process.env.DBUSERNAME, password: process.env.DBPASSWORD, database: process.env.DBDATABASE, connectionLimit: 16});

pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
    conn.end();
});

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/v1/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log('0');
    pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
        console.log('1');
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err0, salt) => {
            console.log('2');
            if (err0) {
                console.error(`Failed to generate salt, got error "${err0}"!`);
                return res.status(500).json({error: 'Failed to register account!', message: 'Failed to generate salt.'});
            }
        
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err1, hash) => {
                console.log('3');
                if (err1) {
                    console.error(`Failed to hash password, got error "${err1}"!`);
                    return res.status(500).json({error: 'Failed to register account!', message: 'Failed to hash password server-side.'});
                }
            
                conn.execute('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, creation_date, token) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())', [req.body.username, hash], (err2, results) => {
                    console.log('4');
                
                        if (err2) {
                            console.error(`Failed to insert data, got message "${err2.stack}"!`);
                            return res.status(500).json({error: 'Failed to register account!', message: 'Failed to insert data to MySQL database.'});
                        }

                        var generatedToken = jwt.sign({id: results.insertId, username: req.body.username, password: hash}, process.env.VERYSECRET, { expiresIn: '1w' });

                        conn.end();
                        return res.status(200).json({message: 'Registration successful!', token: generatedToken});
                    }
                );
            });
        });

        conn.end();
    }).catch(err1 => {
        console.error(`Failed to acquire connection, got message "${err1.stack}"!`);
        return res.status(500).json({error: 'Failed to register account!', message: 'Failed to acquire connection from MySQL connection pool!'});
    });
});

https.createServer({key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')}, app).listen(8080);
```

(It gets timed out when the POST request is made...)

Does anybody know how to fix this?